# A problem about an app

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, image-processing

[image]

Hello, I would like to know about an app or website to draw these kind of graphs. I have tried several websites but they are about pie charts or something like that. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Google can graph functions (just type "plot f(x)=ln(x) and g(x)=ln(-x)") or try Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com).

Comment: Thank you a lot!